# jquery error popup relative

Tags: jquery

on click i want an error msg to popup next to wherever the click occurs. how do i specify the div coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

They'll be two parameters (pageX, pageY) on the event object passed into your mouse event. See [these tutorials for examples](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position).